# Why do the RNAseq reads map to only a certain region of a viral genome?

Tags: rna-sequencing, blast

I am looking at RNAseq data and mapping them to 3 RNA segments from Cucumber Mosaic Virus.

I trimmed the adapters from the fastq files and converted them to fasta, which I searched against a virus database using BLASTN.

The results were confusing:

The reads align to one RNA segment (RNA 1 segment) of this virus but not the other segments. I looked in my BLAST result file the qseqid of this RNA segment of this virus and compared with the ids in my fasta file.

I copied this sequence and I did a NCBI BLAST which gave to me the same result. These 3 segments are in the capsid together, so they should be together. I am sure that they are in this NGS file.

What parameters should do I change?

Comment: I have edited your question. Can you please confirm if this is what you meant? Add more details; for example, length of the reads, number of reads and percentage of reads mapping to your `RNA 1` segment, where are other reads mapping etc.

Comment: Also, you do not generally use BLAST for aligning short RNAseq reads. Try other NGS aligners like Bowtie or STAR (since this is a viral genome you may not need splice site aligners like HISAT).